# Optimise a functional using Euler-Lagrange-Equations gives trivial solution.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a question.

I want to minimise the functional $$L = \int_{\mathbb{R}}y(t)^2dt.$$ And I have the additional constraints, that $y(t) = y(-t)$ for all $t \in\mathbb{R}$
$$\int_\mathbb{R}y(t)dt = 1,\; \int_\mathbb{R}t^2y(t)dt = 1.$$

The solution is supposed to give the function $y(t) + c_1 + c_2t^2=0$, where $c_1,c_2$ are constants given by the constraints.
However, when I try to use the Euler-Lagrange equation for calculus of variations, I get, with $F(t,y,y')=y^2$:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2y, \; \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right) = \frac{d}{dt} (0) = 0.$$
Which leaves me with $2y = 0$ and thus $y=0$.

I don't know how to use the constraints to get the constants $c_1,c_2$ because I only find $y=0$ to be a solution.

If anybody could point out what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Have you heard about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @CheeHan A little, if I use them then I get $\lambda_1(\int_{\mathbb{R}}y(t)dt-1) = 0$ and $\lambda_2(\int_{\mathbb{R}}t^2y(t)dt-1) = 0$, which gives me the optimisation problem $\int(y^2(t)-\lambda_1y-\lambda_2t^2y(t))dt -\lambda_1 - \lambda_2$. Can I then use the Euler-Lebesgue formula on $F = y^2(t)-\lambda_1y-\lambda_2t^2y(t)$?
But then I'm still missing the condition, that $y(t) = y(-t)$. How to I include that?

Comment: You are correct there. The condition $y(t) = y(-t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is saying that $y$ must be an even function, so I would use this to rewrite your functional as $2\int_0^\infty y(t)^2\, dt$.

Comment: @CheeHan Okay, that was a huge help. Thank you :)